# Meaning of "Protect the valley something, something, something, something alive!"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, lyrics

This sentence is from the theme song of an animated series called Kung Fu Panda: Legends of Awesomeness. You can find it on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xllx5TdcRUo).

I found this question here: ["A little something something"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65808/a-little-something-something) but I don't think that the meanings listed there fit in the song. This [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/something-something) and this [Urban Dictionary entry](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=somethin%27%20somethin%27) didn't help either.

However, this [Urban Dictionary entry](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=something%20something) might fit in the lyrics:

> "Something something" means that whatever the person is talking about
>   **isn't worth clarifying**.

I also found a TV special of Family Guy called ["Something, Something, Something, Dark Side"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something,_Something,_Something,_Dark_Side) which is a parody of Star Wars. But I don't think that the songwriter wanted listeners to think that the series is made up of repeated ideas and things not worth mentioning. I can't think of another meaning, though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to the uses you found we also use the word "something" to describe a thing that we can't remember or don't know.

For example, "I can't exactly remember what Alice said. She said something about 'the furious five' and 'alive.'"

This is a very typical use, but not exactly like the one in the song.  In the song, "something" doesn't *describe* the forgotten word, it stands in for the forgotten word:

"Protect the valley, *something* (some word I can't remember), *something* (some word I can't remember), *something* (some word I can't remember), *something* (some word I can't remember) alive"

This is a common* way of singing a song, or quoting a speech, that you only partially remember. It's not formal, so don't use it in an essay for school, or a published article.

*The joke here is that we might expect that a *viewer* of a cartoon show would sing the theme song like this, because they could only remember some of the words. We would not expect the person singing the theme song on the show itself to have forgotten the words.

Comment: **Warning: TV Tropes link.** [Something Something Leonard Bernstein](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SomethingSomethingLeonardBernstein) even explicitly references the Kung Fu Panda example (in the Western Animation section).

Comment: For shorter words and phrases, "La la la" is often used.

Comment: Something could also be a place holder for words not forgotten but not yet written.  I certainly got the impression from listening before I read this answer that they knew they wanted to rhyme "alive" with "five", but had not yet figured out the connection so they used placeholders.  It makes the song sound a little more improvisational.

Comment: *Another sky, another June…Another something, that rhymes with 'June'*